# keep filename while uploading an url with python response library

Tags: python, python-requests

I am using python to upload a file to an api with

```
url = 'http://domain.tld/api/upload'
files = {'file': open('image.jpg', 'rb')}

r = requests.post(url, files=files)
```

this works well and my file is uploaded to the server as `image.jpg`. Now I don't have a local files but an uri instead, so I changed my code to:

```
url = 'http://domain.tld/api/upload'
files = {'file': urlopen('http://domain.tld/path/to/image.jpg')}

r = requests.post(url, files=files)
```

the image is also uploaded sucessfully but it does not preserve it's name and is stored as 'file' (without extension). My question is, how can I upload an url while keeping it's filename (Of course without downloading it first)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the name:

```
 files = {'name': ('image.jpg', urlopen('http://domain.tld/path/to/image.jpg'))}
```

If you look at the post body you will see for your variation:

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="file"
```

And using the code above:

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"; filename="image.jpg"
```

You can see the name is retained in the latter.